# Valid Example of Complex Euclidean Space

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I consider two alphabets $\Sigma_1 = \{1, 2\}^2 = \{ 11, 12, 21, 22\}$ and another one as $\Sigma_2 = \{3, 4\}^2 = \{33, 34, 43, 44\}$, then I define two complex Euclidean space as:
$$X = C^{\Sigma_1} = [i, 2i, 3i, 4i]^T $$
and
$$Y = C^{\Sigma_2} = [5i, 6i, 7i, 8i]^T$$
are these two valid and different examples of complex Euclidean space? Am I not considering spaces of the same dimension?

Comment: How can a column vector be a Euclidean (vector?) space?

Comment: Can you please clarify your notation? I'm with Randall here in that I'm not sure how to make sense of your question

Comment: see that's the problem I'm facing. I just don't know two valid exmaples that could be built with those two alphabet. I'm mixing up space and element of space I guess.